# About the variance positions in Scala

Tags: scala, type-systems, variance

I'm reading the book "programming in scala", and found the variance positions are hard to understand.

```
trait Cat[-T, +U] {
    def meow[W]()
}
```

It says the position of `W` is negative.

What does it mean by "negative"? What can I do and what can't do with the type `W`?

Comment: Careful, if you introduce a type parameter T for meow, then it shadows the parameter T of cat. Your code would be just the same, just clearer, if you wrote def meow[U]...

Comment: @DidierDupont, thank you, and I remove that samples

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12451702/1296806  That's not a great Q&A, unfortunately. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/1296806